# Sorting a vector by Month Name in r

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I am having a vector

```
monthData <- c("April", "June", "May", "August","July","September","December","November","October")
```

Is it possible to sort the vector in the chronological order of month name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the built in `month.name`.

```r
monthData[order(match(monthData, month.name))]
#> [1] "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September"
#> [7] "October"   "November"  "December"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could transform the vector to a factorized vector:

```
fact_monthData<-factor(monthData, levels=month.name)
```

Then you can sort the vector by:

```
sort(fact_monthData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try sort on another vector consisting of full dates, in the same year, with the various month components:

```
dates <- as.Date(paste0("2020-", monthData, "-01"), format="%Y-%b-%d")
monthData[order(dates)]

[1] "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September"
[7] "October"   "November"  "December"
```

**Data:**

```
monthData <- c("April", "June", "May", "August", "July", "September", "December",
               "November","October")
```